# How to improve LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-method-syntax

I am working on an application where a user can filter records by categories.

A record must have 1 but can have many categories. (1-*)

The question I have is, What can I do to improve this search? It currently runs at about an O(n^3) for the following reason:

A transaction may have many records (1-many)
A record may have many categories (1-many)
Iterate through the categories selected for searching

The basic outline of what I am doing is the following:

```
retrieve all announcements

if(startDate and endDate have values)
    model = model.Where(x => x.WADate >= start.Value && x.WADate <= end.Value).ToList();

if(queryString is not null)
    model = model.Where(
                        x => x.WANum.Contains(query) ||
                        x.Tooltip.ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Contains(query)
                        || x.Topic.ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Contains(query)
                    ).ToList();

if (selectedCategories.Count > 0)
        {
            bool HasMatch;
            foreach (var ancmt in announcements)
            {
                HasMatch = false;
                foreach (var cat in selectedCategories)
                {
                    foreach (var xref in ancmt.waXref)
                    {
                        if (cat.ID == xref.WACategoryID)
                        {
                            HasMatch = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(HasMatch)
                {
                    model.Add(new EditViewModel
                    {
                        WATypeID = ancmt.WATypeID,
                        WANum = ancmt.WANum,
                        WATypeName = ancmt.waType.WATypeDescription,
                        Link = ancmt.Link,
                        Tooltip = ancmt.Tooltip,
                        Topic = ancmt.Topic,
                        WADate = ancmt.WADate,
                        WAID = ancmt.WAID,
                    });

                    ancmt.waXref.ToList().ForEach(
                        x => model.Last().Categories.Add(
                            new CategoryViewModel { ID = x.WACategoryID, Name = x.waCategory.WACategory, IsSelected = false }));
                }
            }
        }
        // If no catgories were selected, keep all announcements for next stage of search
        else
        {
            foreach (var ancmt in announcements)
            {
                model.Add(new EditViewModel
                {
                    WATypeID = ancmt.WATypeID,
                    WANum = ancmt.WANum,
                    WATypeName = ancmt.waType.WATypeDescription,
                    Link = ancmt.Link,
                    Tooltip = ancmt.Tooltip,
                    Topic = ancmt.Topic,
                    WADate = ancmt.WADate,
                    WAID = ancmt.WAID,
                });

                ancmt.waXref.ToList().ForEach(
                    x => model.Last().Categories.Add(
                        new CategoryViewModel { ID = x.WACategoryID, Name = x.waCategory.WACategory, IsSelected = false }));
            }
        }
```

I am using Method syntax, not query and prefer to stay in method syntax.

Comment: This doesn't look like a Linq query to me.

Comment: It's difficult to tell from just the code what the expected outcome of the "query" should be.  It looks like you're just setting a match flag on each record.  Instead of doing that, why not run an actual Linq query?

Comment: Real code added @RobertHarvey

Comment: What are your performance measurements telling you is the hot spot in the code, i.e. that part of the code that needs to be optimized?

Comment: Hmmm... Good question. I don't have any metrics. Can you point me in right direction to obtain some performance metrics?

Comment: Use a profiler or put in some StopWatches.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, here is the metrics I received from a few runs. The runs are variations of all possible queries, with fairly little variation in run times. This is operating against approximately 40 test items.
Run 1: 422ms
Run 2: 298ms
Run 3: 428ms
Run 4: 299ms
Run 5: 427ms
Run 6: 370ms

Comment: Looks like "UI-chaotic data passed to some ninja logic and back to UI somehow whatever"-style to me.

Comment: OK.  Where is the majority of time being spent?  Which line(s) of code takes the most time?

Comment: I'm going to say that the n^3 loop structure is where the most time is taking place. @StefanSteinegger, I have a view model for the View, which is why the data "looks" chaotic. It needs some refactoring, but no time to refactor when you have 3 weeks between day 1 and deployment.

Comment: Post your sample data (your 40 test items).  Include in your question the expected output.

Comment: That's not really an option. Considering the data can be searched for in a variety of ways, the "expected" output can vary. However, the following is always true about the result set.
1. A user can search for a string. The string may or may not exist in the record.
2. A user can narrow (filter) results by categories; there are 10
3. A user can narrow the range of the result set by date.
4. A user may use one or any combination of the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any real performance gains it would be best to create specific Stored Procedures to handle the true heavy lifting processing in the database and not on the client PC.

Comment: Took this route and created some stored procedures to return the data in a slimmed down result set.